# Output standard OK / FAILED messages from custom init.d script

Tags: daemon, sh, init.d

I have a few questions regarding an init script I'm writing. I haven't actually done it from scratch before so there are probably several tips and tricks I don't know about. Also, shell script is not something I have used a lot so the syntax took a bit of getting used to.

First of all I have a function to see if the application is running. The reason for this, instead of **lockfiles** or similar, is that I only want ONE instance and the application is a bit buggy and plugins can sometime linger even if the main application is killed.

So I have something like.

```
isrunning() {
  pids=`ps aux | grep -e 'FooBar' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
  if [ ! -n "$pids" ]; then
    return 1
  else
    return 0
  fi
}
```

Is there a better way?

I start the main application with

```
daemon --user apache "./FooBar"
```

but that hung the script execution on that line until **FooBar** was terminated.

```
daemon --user apache "FooBar&"
```

works though. But it looks like the **[OK]** / **[FAILED]** that shows up when running the init script is actually output by the **daemon** function? So even if the execution fails, **daemon** still reports **[OK]** since the process of **FooBar** is detached.

Is there a way to get **daemon** NOT to get stuck without detaching the process? I have tried the **-d** option etc but no luck.

Otherwise I was thinking of just doing a **sleep 3** and then check **isrunning** which works fine. But then I don't know how to print the **[OK**] / **[FAILED]** messages in the nice pretty way that init scripts normally do. Is there perhaps a function one can use to print this in the standard form?

**UPDATE**

I found the solution to printing the messages. It seems it actually are functions for this.
**success** and **failure** will print the messages.

The daemon issue remain though. Any way to get rid of **&**?

**UPDATE 2**

I found a workaround and used

```
su -m -c "./FooBar&" apache
```

and checking if the application was running after that. Depending on the result I print the correct message.

Comment: Could you elaborate how you've fixed it ? Like a copy paste of your script. I have the same issue. Thanks !

Comment: This was a while ago and I don't think I still have the script in question. I'll check around and see what I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to printing the messages. It seems it actually are functions for this. success and failure will print the messages.

Answer (score 1):

The script you are using is the wrong answer to a FAQ.  Try this simpler version instead:

```
isrunning () {
  pids=`ps aux | awk '/FooBar/{print $2}'`
  if [ ! -n "$pids" ]; then
    return 1
  else
    return 0
  fi
}
```

I'm very very tempted to set the exit code from within awk as well:

```
isrunning () { ps aux | awk '/FooBar/{print $2;exit 0}END{exit 1}'; }
```

If you are on Linux, perhaps you should be using `pidof` instead, though.